# Error while changing path for image in joomla website

Tags: php, html, image, css, joomla

I am shifting all images and pages from one server to another server for Joomla website.

server 1 : Image path is as under in css file. From server 1, I want to shift images to server 2.

```
main-bg {background:url(../images/main-bg.gif) repeat 0 0;}
```

path : /home/wealthc5/public_html/images

server 2 :

```
.main-bg {background:url(../images/main-bg.gif) repeat 0 0;}
```

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WC/images

Pls tell me how to set path in server 2 for the same images.

Thank you.

Comment: Paths are relative to the css file's location, so they should work the same server to server.

Comment: but its not working there in server 2....I have copied all css files from server 1 to server 2 but still background images does not work bcz of change in path.

Answer (score 0):

As @David Fritsch states paths in the CSS should work as they are relative to the website root. It's more likely to be a configuration issue than a need to change the CSS.

Try to diagnose the problem:

1. Check what path the browser is looking at: try Right-clicking a
   broken image and selecting "Open image in new window/tab" to see the
   address the browser is trying to access.
2. Check your new servers access logs to compare the image request(s) with
   the actual file location.
3. Look for things like extra directories in the path the browser is trying access (or missing ones).

To get better help provide more detail in your question, like the URL for the site or the HTML in the page versus the path to the actual image files.